# memory leak in overloading operator =

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have this constructor for matrix to allocate memory

```
class Matrix 
{

public:
    int** matrix;
    int cols;
    int rows;
};
Matrix::Matrix(int row, int col)
{
    cols = col;
    rows = row;
    matrix = new int*[rows];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[cols];
    }
}
```

now I want to overload the operator =, but I can't figure out how to write the function and allocate the new memory, without getting a memory leak, or not having enough memory.

The matrix the I'll do the = on it, already has memory allocated for it, so can i delete the memory and make new memory on the size of the other one?

for now I have this on the operator =

```
this->rows = other.rows;
this->cols = other.cols;

int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < this->rows; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < this->cols; j++)
    {
        this->matrix[i][j] = other.matrix[i][j];
    }

}
return *this;
```

Comment: Do you have a copy constructor?

Comment: yes, i did a copy constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idiomatic way is to use the copy/swap idiom. See [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

The assignment is then reduced to

```
Matrix& operator=(Matrix copy){
   swap(*this, copy);
   return *this;
}
```

See the linked question for all the perks you gain by using this idiom.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend switching from manually allocating arrays to using `std::vector`

```
class Matrix 
{
public:
    Matrix(int row, int col);
    int cols;
    int rows;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
};

Matrix::Matrix(int row, int col)
:  cols(col),
   rows(row),
   matrix(rows, std::vector<int>(cols))
{ }
```

Now you can let the compiler generate your copy assignment operator, and the other constructors, destructor, etc. This class is now copyable, moveable, and doesn't leak memory because `matrix` now uses RAII semantics instead of you having to manage its memory.

Answer (score 0):

First you can reallocate the each column using the delete operator.

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
           delete []matrix[i];
    }
```

Then you can deallocate pointers to each row.

```
 delete []matrix;
```

After that you can allocate the new matrix as required from the one passed as argument.